# How to prevent artifacts when doing line drawing in processing

Tags: processing

I'm drawing some generative shapes in processing. Just a couple bezier curvers which have points that are controlled by points that exert a gravity on them.

The problem is that my lines are forming artifacts, they aren't crisp and smooth. Is this just a matter of the size of my drawing? Any help would be appreciated, I've uploaded an example image where you can see some weird stuff going on with the lines.

[image: example of artifacts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks pretty cool.
If you want crisper lines you should call the [smooth()](http://processing.org/reference/smooth_.html) function once in `setup()`. I see in Processing 2.0+ you can also control the amount of smoothness to a certain degree.

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by

> lines are forming artifacts

but unless it's the lines' antialiasing which smooth() would fix,
then that would be the [Moiré pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback George. I am already using smooth but I will checkout processing 2.0 and play around with the smoothness. I guess not much I can do about the artifacts, it does appear to be the Moiré pattern.